# Getting a cloudfront 404 issue upon trying to open a website on ec2 using firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, firefox, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to open a website from my ec2 machine using firefox browser. I am getting a 404 each time and the browser is not able to load css and other assets.The error is from cloudfront **X-cache:Error from cloudfront**. I am not able to debug the issue. I am able to open the website on my local machine.
Thanks a lot:)

Comment: By default Cloudfront wil cache errors. Does that EC2 instance have outbound access to the internet? If so, I would first try invalidating your Cloudfront distribution and try again.

Comment: Thanks Jack. However,I don't have a cloudfront distribution. The EC2 instance is facing the internet directly. The website that I am trying to access is a third party website which I am trying to scrape. At this point,I can only think of some firefox settings related issue on the EC2 side. Thanks again.